# Passing pointer to any member function as class template argument

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T, typename M, M Method>
class ProxyObject
{
public:

    template<typename... Args>
    void Invoke (T& Object, _In_ Args&&... A)
    {
        (void)(Object.*Method)(std::forward<Args>(A)...);
    }
};

class Object
{
public:

    int MyMethod (int Val)
    {
        wcout << L"Hello!" << endl;
        return Val;
    }
};


int wmain ()
{
    Object myObj;
    ProxyObject<Object, decltype(&Object::MyMethod), &Object::MyMethod> obj;

    obj.Invoke(myObj, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

The `decltype(&Object::MyMethod)` seems redundant in the definition of `obj`. Is there any way to make the `ProxyObject` automatically infer the type of the pointer-to-member-function being passed, so that I can define `obj` as follows:

```
ProxyObject<Object, &Object::MyMethod> obj;
```

Comment: [P0127R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0127r0.html)

Comment: @cpplearner That's nice. The timing is almost uncanny. Still hoping for a solution that I can use today though 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's impossible for class template, because you have to specify the member function type explicitly.

Template function could help you lot with the argument deduction:

```
template<typename T, typename M, typename... Args>
void invoke (T& Object, M Method, Args&&... A)
{
    (void)(Object.*Method)(std::forward<Args>(A)...);
}
```

then

```
invoke(myObj, &Object::MyMethod, 10);
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/cqOxnE)

Comment: That's unfortunate. I do want the member function to be part of the class type though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Class template need specify the template parameter explicity, and there're both type template parameter and nontype template parameter, so...